# Responsive SVG sizing

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG:

```
body {
    background-color: #dad9c7;
    svg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <g>
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="0" fill="#d5835b" />
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="150" fill="#d47966" />
        <rect width="1000" height="126" x="0" y="300" fill="#b66961" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="425" fill="#d17385" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="525" fill="#aa617c" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="625" fill="#a36d8f" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="725" fill="#736d87" />
        <rect width="1000" height="176" x="0" y="825" fill="#313d53" />
    </g>        

</svg>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: svg-screenshot]

How can I do the following?

1. Keep heights of colored strips the same when scaling the window (not scale).
2. Stretch colored strips horizontally to the edges of the viewport on either side left and right.
3. Stretch the top-most rectangle to the top of the screen so the upper third of the viewport is orange and stretch the bottom-most rectangle to the bottom of the viewport so that the lower third of the viewport is purple.
4. Always keep the "square" centered vertically which already works with CSS, but however the SVG is manipulated to solve would have to keep this into account.

Here is an example of how this would look: As the window gets taller, the colored rectangles will stay in the middle, but the top orange and bottom purple would be cut off based on the height of the viewport.

[image: svg-screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do the following?
>
> 1. Keep heights of colored strips the same when scaling the window (not scale).

You are already doing this by setting height to 400px.

> 2. Stretch colored strips horizontally to the edges of the viewport on either side left and right.

Set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` on the SVG. See below.

```css
body {
    background-color: #dad9c7;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <g>
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="0" fill="#d5835b" />
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="150" fill="#d47966" />
        <rect width="1000" height="126" x="0" y="300" fill="#b66961" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="425" fill="#d17385" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="525" fill="#aa617c" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="625" fill="#a36d8f" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="725" fill="#736d87" />
        <rect width="1000" height="176" x="0" y="825" fill="#313d53" />
    </g>        

</svg>
```

> 3. Stretch the top-most rectangle to the top of the screen so the upper third of the viewport is orange and stretch the bottom-most rectangle to the bottom of the viewport so that the lower third of the viewport is purple.

You cannot automatically stretch the rectangle itself with CSS. But one way you could do it is to use pseudo elements to colour the top and bottom halves of the parent element with matching colours.

```css
body {
    background-color: #dad9c7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  background-color: #d5835b;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #313d53;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <g>
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="0" fill="#d5835b" />
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="150" fill="#d47966" />
        <rect width="1000" height="126" x="0" y="300" fill="#b66961" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="425" fill="#d17385" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="525" fill="#aa617c" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="625" fill="#a36d8f" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="725" fill="#736d87" />
        <rect width="1000" height="176" x="0" y="825" fill="#313d53" />
    </g>        

</svg>
```

> 4. Always keep the "square" centered vertically which already works with CSS, but however the SVG is manipulated to solve would have to keep this into account.

N/A here.

**Alternate pure-SVG solution**

There is also a pure SVG solution using nested `<svg>` elements.  The only CSS we are using is just to ensure the SVG occupies the full size of the page.

It works by making the top and bottom rectangles extend outside the `viewBox` by an extra 1000 pixels. To make sure they are visible, we set `overflow="visible"`.  1000 is an arbitrary value.  If you want to support screens > 2400 pixels high, then you could choose a larger value.

The inner SVG gets centred vertically using a combination of a `y` offset and a `transform` that shifts it up by 200px. This is equivalent to the common `top: 50%; transform: translate(0,-50%)"` trick to vertically centre CSS block elements.

```css
body {
    background-color: #dad9c7;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#mysvg {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg">

  <g transform="translate(0, -200)">
    <svg width="100%" height="400px"
         y="50%" transform="translate(0, -200)"
         viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none"
         overflow="visible">

      <g>
        <rect width="1000" height="1151" x="0" y="-1000" fill="#d5835b" />
        <rect width="1000" height="151" x="0" y="150" fill="#d47966" />
        <rect width="1000" height="126" x="0" y="300" fill="#b66961" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="425" fill="#d17385" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="525" fill="#aa617c" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="625" fill="#a36d8f" />
        <rect width="1000" height="101" x="0" y="725" fill="#736d87" />
        <rect width="1000" height="1176" x="0" y="825" fill="#313d53" />
     </g>

    </svg>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Plus1 for being incredibly sophisticated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use media queries or css styling for that since a svg does not support that. If you really need to that with an SVG, you will need some Javascript to accomplish your desired effect. In your case, I guess it is simpler to create that using html and css with some media queries.

The only thing you can control when scaling/displaying a SVG is the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. A detailed description can be found [here](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/).

Comment: Huh? What makes you think that SVGs do not support CSS or media queries?

Comment: Can we change `x/y/width/height` of `<rect>` elements using css? Can we say `width=100%` for rects?

Comment: In SVG1.1 only style properties can be modified with CSS. Not geometric attributes like position and size. However in SVG2 you can. But you didn't say you were talking about them.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau So do you think the above Problem can be solved with css only, right now?

Comment: I do not care which version of SVG I use, only if it will work in the latest version of Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @philipp Yes. See my answer. I have provided two solutions.